# message in channel discord bot

Tags: python, discord

I would like to know how I send a message in a certain channel (in python) with commands

My commands :

`@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("Administrator")
async def message(ctx, message):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send(message)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to get channel id that you want to send message

```
await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
chn = bot.get_channel(721666738835685437)
await chn.send(message)
```